Check printing for multiple accounts
I can find checks to order that allow computer printing, but the account info (account number, routing number, bank name, etc) is all pre printed. Is there a way to order checks that do not have all this pre printed, so I can have a printer loaded with blank checks that can print on multiple accounts without changing what papers are physically loaded in the paper tray? The software is not an issue, I just need the appropriate blanks.

Yes, you can order blank checks and print the MICR line yourself. But you'll need a special printer with a special ink to do that, you cannot do that with a regular home or office printer. MICR ink is special because it includes magnetized particles that are being read through special sensors when the check is run through a check scanner.
Order blank checks from any company that provides check printing services. You'll need to ask them about the ink, some may carry it too, or your printer manufacturer may provide a special MICR-compatible cartridge. Note that MICR ink should only be used for the machine readable line at the bottom, not the rest of the check, so you'll need a printer that supports that.

And note that without a correct MICR line, banks are no longer required to accept checks. The days of being able to cash a check written on a blackboard, or on other odd objects, are long gone.

Wait, so I can't write a check on a cow anymore? /s

Regulations require a MICR line printed in magnetic ink/toner, but my understanding is that nobody does actual MICR anymore, it's all OCR. Looking at common check scanners, none have a MICR head. People print checks with normal printers and get away with it fine.

I think it depends on the country. I believe in the US, after the introduction of remote deposits, the MICR ink becomes less important since OCR is in fact being used for most parts. In other places it may not be so.

@littleadv: Nor on "the short off your back." Banks got the restriction approved about a decade ago in exchange for promising faster processing of checks. Yes, you may still be able to get away with it if the bank manager is sufficiently amused, but no promises. Ss far as non-magnetic goes... I'm not sure of current status. Certainly many of us are now depositing checks via scan, but I think the bank reserves the right to tell us a particular check must be submitted physically , partly to guard against some of the scams we've seen reported on this site.

OCR vs MICR issues aside, Why shouldn't the magnetic ink be used for the entire check? Because it's more expensive than regular ink?

Hmmm there's probably no actual prohibition actually, you're right. But yes, it's much more expensive

Thanks for asking the question I didn't know to ask! Sounds a bit more complex than my situation justifies, looks like I will just need to deal with various blank types.

Yes. The product you are looking for is called “blank check stock.” A Google search for this term will yield quite a few options for sale online as well as availability from big box office supply stores.

Perfect, thanks!
